# an icon less app after installing ipa file directly

Tags: ios, ipa

I have an apple developer account and i got an adhoc ipa file from my project. Now i would like to install it directly. based on what i found on internet i created two files:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
            <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://mobile.myapp.com/ios_version/manifest.plist">
                    Download
            </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://mobile.myapp.com/ios_download_link/myapp.ipa</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>display-image</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://mobile.myapp.com/ios_download_link/logo-57x57.png</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>full-size-image</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://mobile.myapp.com/ios_download_link/logo-512x512.png</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.myapp.flight</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>1.0.6</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>myapp</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

as the result when i click on the download link on safari a popup shows up to install the app. but after installation it's just a useless app without my icon and when i click on the app nothing happens.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean .html and .plist as the file extensions instead of .json?  Does the provisioning profile in your IPA include your device UDID? How did you export the IPA from Xcode?

Comment: @Paulw11 . yeah I meant html and plist. sorry about that and thank you. no i did not include my udid. i wish i could give this link to every body. for exporting this ipa i created an "ios distribution" certificate and exported ad hoc version of my app.

Comment: You can't distribute apps generally outside of the App Store.  You can distribute an ad-hoc build only to devices whose UDIDs are included in the embedded provisioning profile.  If you want to distribute an app generally for testing then you should look at TestFlight in App Store Connect.